# Prompt user to enable GPS in Mobile Site

Tags: html, mobile, gps, geolocation

I am using the HTML5 Geolocation API to get user's current location & everything works fine when the user has enabled GPS & location services. But when it is turned off is there someway I can prompt the user to enable GPS from within my Mobile Site similar to the way it is done in an Android App?

Comment: This should be done by browser level directly. I have seen it in iOS and Android.

Comment: Browser does it only when GPS is turned on in settings. My question is how do I prompt the user to turn on their GPS when they have switched it off??